# Thymeleaf: Create dynamic URL query String in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, urlencode, thymeleaf

I am new in thymeleaf, i want to create dynamic query string using thymeleaf url. For pagination i am using common fragment and include fragment in all pages. There is search option in all pages and also need pagination for search. So, we need to pass, dynamic query string in pagination for searching criteria. But when i create the query string dynamic, the URL encode the special character like `=` and `&`. Following is my code

```
<!-- Pagination Bar -->
<div th:fragment='paginationbar(searchArguments)'>
  <div class='pagination pagination-centered'>
    <ul>
      <li th:class="${page.firstPage}? 'disabled' : ''">
        <span th:if='${page.firstPage}'> First</span>
        <a th:if='${not page.firstPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=0,size=${page.size},${searchArguments})}'>First</a>
      </li>
      <li th:class="${page.hasPreviousPage}? '' : 'disabled'">
        <span th:if='${not page.hasPreviousPage}'>&lt;&lt;</span>
        <a th:if='${page.hasPreviousPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.currentNumber - 2},size=${page.size},${searchArguments})}' title='Go to previous page'>&lt;&lt;</a>
      </li>
       <li th:each='item : ${page.items}' th:class="${item.current}? 'active' : ''">
        <span th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>1</span>
        <a th:if='${not item.current}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${item.number - 1},size=${page.size},${searchArguments})}'><span th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
      </li> 
      <li th:class="${page.hasNextPage}? '' : 'disabled'">
        <span th:if='${not page.hasNextPage}'>&gt;&gt;</span>
        <a th:if='${page.hasNextPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.currentNumber},size=${page.size},${searchArguments})}' title='Go to next page'>&gt;&gt;</a>
      </li>
      <li th:class="${page.lastPage}? 'disabled' : ''">
        <span th:if='${page.lastPage}'>Last </span>
        <a th:if='${not page.lastPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.totalPages - 1},size=${page.size},${searchArguments})}'>Last</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Include the fragment in page:

```
<div th:include="admin/fragments/pagination-fragment :: paginationbar('title='+${title}+'&amp;status='+${status})" th:if="${title != null}"></div>
```

When view the source code for page, following URL is create:

```
<a href="/sample/admin/search-category?page=1&amp;size=5&amp;title%3Dtil%26status%3D"><span>2</span></a>
```

In above URL the browser convert `title='+${title}+'&amp;status='+${status}` into `title%3Dtil%26status%3D`. How we set actual query string for pagination link?

**Update Thymeleaf  Configuration**

```
public class MultiViewResolverConfig{

@Autowired
private Environment env;

/** 
 * This method is used to create tiles view resolver which have 
 * view resolver first priority for resolve response view
 * */
@Bean
public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
    TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
    resolver.clearCache();
    resolver.setCache(Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("tiles.cache")));
    resolver.setCacheLimit(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("tiles.cache.limit")));
    return resolver;
}

/** 
 * This method is used to configure tiles for application and 
 * specify which definitions files are used. 
 * This method create a bean and register. 
 * */
@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigure(){
    TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    configurer.setDefinitions(new String[]{"classpath:tiles-definitions/user-definitions.xml", 
            "classpath:tiles-definitions/public-definitions.xml", "classpath:tiles-definitions/admin-definitions.xml"});
    //configurer.setValidateDefinitions(true);
    //configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
    return configurer;
}

/* Thymeleaf configuration */
private ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("thm.cache")));
    templateResolver.setCacheTTLMs(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("thm.cache.limit")));
    return templateResolver;
}

private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

private ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    thymeleafViewResolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafView.class);
    thymeleafViewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"admin/**"});
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}


/* JSP view resolver */

private InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver  = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setCache(Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("url.cache")));
    resolver.setCacheLimit(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("url.cache.limit")));
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver setupViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    resolvers.add(tilesViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(thymeleafViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(jspViewResolver());

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    viewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    return viewResolver;
}}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your encoding issue. Can you share your thymeleaf configuration ?

Answer (score 8):

This problem have simple solution, i am trying to create the URL from thymeleaf `href` attribute like this:

```
th:href='@{${page.url}(page=0,size=${page.size},${searchArguments})}'
```

But there is no need to pass parameter to the thymeleaf `th:href` attribute. Just append the query string with your `th:href` attribute like this:

```
th:href='@{${page.url}(page=0,size=${page.size})}+${searchArguments}'
```

In this, thymeleaf create the URL and we append our dynamic query string with URL.

Comment: Good to know. I think you have a typo in your post : after _${page.size}_ it should be **)** instead of **}**, no ?

Comment: Thanks @heRoy for identify my typo mistake.